How to diagnose cause of overheating coolant?
Context:

1998 Toyota Camry: radiator replaced 12 month ago
Coolant suddenly began overheating and overflowed onto parking lot

Temperature gauge indicated critical / hot and engine was immediately shut down to prevent damage.  After radiator was sufficiently cooled, its capped was removed and it had plenty of coolant.
Vehicle was road tested and temperature gauge indicated nominal. Upon reaching destination: engine was allowed to idle for one minute to see if overheating condition could be reproduced => temperature remained nominal.
What tests can be performed to determine root cause of overheating?
Does it make sense to replace the thermostat?
Is there a simple test to confirm a bad thermostat?

In addition to replacing the t-stat, does the cooling fan run? Several ways to test fan operation; wire fan directly to battery, if ac works - turn it on (cooling fan always runs to force air thru ac condenser coil and hot radiator or if the 87a relay is part of fan operation - jumper across relay socket terminals 30 and 87. This sends 12v power to the fan.

@FDryer.  Good idea!   Will test it after tomorrow hurricane.   Any suggestions for testing the thermostat?

Removing it and immersing it in water while dipping a thermometer in the water/t-stat as heat is applied until the t-stat opens and observing temperature at opening is the only way to determine t-stat operation. If its original, at 26 yrs old, replace it. A somewhat easier method of measuring coolant temps is with an inexpensive hand held infrared temperature probe, aiming its spot laser circle on hot objects. Aimed at the t-stat housing on a fully warmed engine, radiator, hoses, whatever, should give an idea of coolant temps.
